# How to alter a column which is a primary key in the table and a foreign key in another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run the following sql query:

```
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY USER_ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

But `USER_ID` is a foreign key on another table. What is the best way to change this column?

This is the error that I get:

```
Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'USER_ID': used in a foreign key constraint 'order_detail_ibfk_1' of table 'test.order_detail'
```

Comment: data type for foreign key and referred column should be same.
Try to change data type of reference column first.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be [multistep](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE other_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name
ALTER TABLE other_table MODIFY USER_ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY USER_ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
ALTER TABLE other_table ADD FOREIGN KEY ...
```

> In MySQL 5.7, the server prohibits changes to foreign key columns that
>   have the potential to cause loss of referential integrity. It also
>   prohibits changes to the data type of such columns that may be unsafe.
>   For example, changing VARCHAR(20) to VARCHAR(30) is permitted, but
>   changing it to VARCHAR(1024) is not because that alters the number of
>   length bytes required to store individual values. A workaround is to
>   use ALTER TABLE ... DROP FOREIGN KEY before changing the column
>   definition and ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY afterward.

Comment: Can you please this new question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785899/column-is-there-but-when-i-try-to-delete-it-says-no-column-in-mysql

Comment: Answered it just now

Comment: Yes, I did finally. Check my answer on the other question. I will post my answer for this question as well. I voted up for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: well that's basically my answer but I didn't know the exact name of the foreign key at the time since that wasn't included in your question.

Comment: The name of the column was `USER_ID` but mySQL adds the index with it and hence the name changes, which I did not know and that is why I got error. The general syntax for deleting a foreign key reference in a MySQL table is like this: `ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY table_name_fk_symbol;` So in my case the updated query was : `ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP FOREIGN KEY ORDER_DETAIL_ibfk_1;
 `

Comment: yes thats what I said: "ALTER TABLE other_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name"

Comment: Yes then according to you if item_id is the foreign key what would be the syntax?

Comment: The column name doesn't have anything to do with dropping the foreign key