# Column is there, but when I try to delete it says no column in MYSQL? **Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP...**

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I try to run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP foreign key USER_ID;
```

It says:

```
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'USER_ID'; check that column/key exists
```

When I run:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP COLUMN USER_ID
```

It says:

```
Error Code: 1553. Cannot drop index 'USER_ID': needed in a foreign key constraint   0.098 sec
```

But when I run:

```
desc ORDER_DETAIL;
```

I get:

```
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra
ORDER_ID,int(11),NO,PRI,NULL,
USER_ID,int(11),NO,MUL,NULL,
ORDER_DATE,date,YES,,NULL,
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: You're dropping the `foreign key` constraint on `ORDER_ID`, but you don't drop the column.

Comment: @e4c5 When I try to drop the foreign key it asks to check if the column exists or not. When I try to drop the column itself it says that it is a foreign key

Comment: But the user id from order is not used as a fk. User id from user is the fk which i wanted to edit. For that I have to remove this user id from order.

Comment: @e4c5 Hey I gave another answer, which was what I followed.

Comment: Hi, just noticed! That happens to be my answer too! (in your case you had the benefit of knowing the exact name of the index, I didn't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MySQL creates an index for the foreign keys so directly trying to drop the foreign key does not work. So the answers provided here does not work.

The right sql query that worked for me is this:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP FOREIGN KEY ORDER_DETAIL_ibfk_1;
```

The important thing to notice here is `_ibfk_1`

And only after that I could drop the column by using:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP COLUMN USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to drop the foreign key. For that what you need to give is the name of the foreign key. To find the name of the foreign key, do SHOW CREATE TABLE. Then use that in the ALTER TABLE

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP foreign key key_name_from_show_create;
```

If it's really the column you want to drop

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP COLUMN USER_ID;
```

Comment: yes, you need to drop the foreign key before you can drop the column. I think I mentioned that in your other question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop Foreign Key constraint then use constraint name:

```
alter table ORDER_DETAIL drop constraint USER_ID_CONSTRAINT
```

here USER_ID_CONSTRAINT is the constraint name.

If you want to drop column then use this:

```
alter table ORDER_DETAIL drop column USER_ID
```

To get all constraint name you can use this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_NAME = 'table to be checked';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in below steps

1) drop foreign constraint

```sql
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL 
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_order_detail // name of your foreign key
```

2) then run below command to drop column

```sql
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL DROP COLUMN USER_ID;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!